# Problem with Firewatir requiring different version of activesupport

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir, activesupport, firewatir

I have a script that uses Watir to retrieve information from Web pages. It works fine as a standalone script. Now I would like to create a Padrino Rake task based on it, and attempt to run the script results in an error:

can't activate activesupport (= 2.3.9) for "firewatir-1.6.7", already activated activesupport-3.0.3 for "padrino-core-0.9.19"

I understand the reason for the problem: Firwatir demands an older version of activesupport. But can this demand be overruled?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried padrino-core-0.9.15? it uses activesupport 2.3.8

> gem install padrino-core -v 0.9.15

that would be the first thing I'd try.

Dave

Comment: That would help, sure. But it is Padrino that is an essential part of the project. Watir is only used in some helper code. So it feels wrong to go back to an older Padrino version just to make it compatible with inappropriately behaving auxilliary component.